# How do I tell my dancer app to serialize objects in its cache?

Tags: json, perl, memcached, dancer

I'm using a CHI interface to memcached (or File in devel) in my Dancer app, but I'm getting an error in the serializer when I cache an object.  I have the following in my dancer config:

```
engines:
  JSON:
    allow_blessed: 1
    convert_blessed: 1
```

What else do I need?

```
Error message:
Error while loading bin/app.pl: encountered object 'C3M::CMF=HASH(0x3ef8aa8)', but neither allow_blessed nor convert_blessed settings are enabled at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10/CHI/Serializer/JSON.pm line 19.
```

Comment: [`#dancer`](http://irc.perl.org) requests clarification: "It's possible you put the config key in the wrong place, it is impossible to tell with that little information though."

Comment: I don't understand this **`/usr/lib/python5/site_python/5.10/CHI/Serializer/JSON.pm`**

Comment: I just voted to close this as "not a real question". If you come up with a reasonable explanation of **`/usr/lib/python5/site_python/5.10/CHI/Serializer/JSON.pm`**, no one else will agree, and you'll probably get an answer. However, right now, there are too many unknowns and confounding factors.

Comment: yeah, I guess that kinda needs explanation...  I have a greasemonkey script which changes perl to python in html content - sort of a joke...  I haven't seen it change it in input boxes before, maybe stackoverflow actually uses the content during the submission.

Comment: In addition to the JSON key in engines, I have a template_toolkit: key which is working as expected (changing the start/stop tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHI::Serializer::JSON doesn't use the same serializer as Dancer::Serializer::JSON.  Dancer::Serializer::JSON uses setting('engines') in config.yml, but there's no way to send configuration options to CHI::Serializer::JSON.

*workaround*:

```
use CHI::Serializer::JSON; 
my $JSON = JSON->new->utf8->canonical;
$JSON->allow_blessed(1);
$JSON->convert_blessed(1);
*CHI::Serializer::JSON::serialize   = sub { $JSON->encode( $_[1] ) };
*CHI::Serializer::JSON::deserialize = sub { $JSON->decode( $_[1] ) };
```